# Listview items spreading till full width of screen

Tags: android, listview

I use a listview to chat messages between two users. I want to set the background color of chat messages sent by the receiver as blue and some other color for the sender. I also want to limit the size of the listview item to `wrap_content` but it doesn't seems to be working, hence the background color spreads all across the width of the item.
[image: Message sent by receiver]

Following is the code of the activity which contains listview:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
tools:context=".ChatScreen">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/lMsgs"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
                android:divider="@null"/>

            <EditText
                android:text=""
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bSendMsg" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/sendd"
                android:id="@+id/bSendMsg"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lMsgs"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/media_attach_menu" />

    </io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Code for listview item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->
<RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_gravity="left"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Username"
    android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvUsername"
    android:id="@+id/innerRL">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:text="Message"
        />

    <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:maxHeight="50dp"
        android:maxWidth="50dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:text="Timestamp"
    android:id="@+id/tvTime"
    android:layout_below="@id/innerRL"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `android:background="@drawable/bg"` into your parentlayout means `FrameLayout` therefore it apply to your all view not single row remove from there and you can apply this background to your listview item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="left"
   android:background="@drawable/yourbackground"
   android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:text="Username"
    android:id="@+id/tvUsername"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />
  ----
```

Comment: So because of the background my listview items are spreading across the whole width?

Comment: no it depend on your layout's width if you set `wrap_content` than not in full width other wise it contains full width

Comment: Can you review my code again please? The width for listview and its items is `wrap_content`

Comment: I changed the height and width of listview as you said but It didn't help

Comment: you have must add background to your listitem layout not in listview layout

Comment: Well neither did I think it should work nor did it work

Comment: I saw the answer precisely. I removed the background from listview and added it to the root of listview item. It shouldn't have worked and it didn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112780/discussion-between-abhishek-patel-and-akash-aggarwal).